# PDOException error when trying to push to production with Laravel 5.1 upgrades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to deploy my recently upgraded Laravel 4.2 app to Laravel 5.1 on my server.  Everything seems to be working, but when I try running `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'bryan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I've gotten similar errors before, but this time I'm pretty sure I have the .env file set up with the correct database credentials.  What confuses me is why it's saying "using password:  NO" as I know I do want and need to use a password with my database, and I think when I had similar issues with incorrect database credentials with my Laravel 4.2 version it had said "using password:  YES".  I'm guessing this has something to do with the problem - is there a way from within my Laravel 5.1 code to turn this from a "NO" to  "YES", or does the problem lay somehow in my database credentials still?

My config/database.php mysql code:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, at some point between Laravel 4 and Laravel 5.1, the default .env variable DB_PASS got changed to DB_PASSWORD.  All of the other default variable names appear to have been left unchanged.  Making sure that both your .env and database.php files contain the newer default name of DB_PASSWORD should resolve the problem along with noting anywhere else that password may have been used.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database.php in your config folder, compare the file with Github repository, and optionally reset your user password.

Comment: Do you know why it's saying "using password" NO" instead of "YES"?  I don't see anything wrong with the database.php file.  It's got all the correct ENV constants referenced there.